# WPF Performance issue in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Hello Can anyone tell where did I made mistake in code below,

```
<ListView x:Name="ServiceListView" 
                                  Loaded="ServiceListView_Loaded" 
                                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                  VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                                  GridViewColumnHeader.Click="ServiceListSort"
                                  ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
                                  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
                                <ListView.View>

                                    <GridView>
                                        <GridViewColumn  Width="50">
                                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Status}" x:Name="StartService" Checked="StartService_Checked" GroupName="{Binding ServiceName}" Style="{DynamicResource StartServiceStyle}"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        </GridViewColumn>
                                        <GridViewColumn  Width="50" >
                                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate.Resources>
                                                        <local:InvertBooleanConverter x:Key="InvertBooleanConverter" />
                                                    </DataTemplate.Resources>
                                                    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource InvertBooleanConverter}}" Checked="StopService_Checked"  x:Name="StopService"  GroupName="{Binding ServiceName}" Style="{DynamicResource StopServiceStyle}" />
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        </GridViewColumn>
                                        <GridViewColumn Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ReccomendedStatus}">
                                            <GridViewColumn.Header>
                                                <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Recommendation"/>
                                            </GridViewColumn.Header>
                                        </GridViewColumn>
                                        <GridViewColumn Width="750" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ServiceName}">
                                            <GridViewColumn.Header>
                                                <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Description"/>
                                            </GridViewColumn.Header>
                                        </GridViewColumn>
                                    </GridView>
                                </ListView.View>
                            </ListView>
```

Currently it has 20-40 items which are visible only 7, it takes around 5-7 seconds, removing both radiobutton Checked event time reduces to 2-4 seconds

```
private void ServiceListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceListView.ItemsSource = DATA_CONTROLS.ServiceData.Values;
    }

public static Dictionary<int, DataObject> ServiceData = new Dictionary<int, DataObject>();
```

Why it takes so long to show in msdn I saw that showing 1000 items only takes 1.6 second, why this method which contains 20-40 items takes 5-7 seconds? I really need to know what causing such performance issue. Thank you.

Found a issue: While I setting: `ServiceListView.ItemsSource = DATA_CONTROLS.ServiceData.Values;` It automaticly fires radiobutton events which would cause such performance drop, also usage IsAsynch improved also performance.

Answer (score 1):

Add 'IsAsync=True' in your ListView,to increase a performance

Comment: Much better, also notice slightly faster then I set fixed size of listview instead of auto.

Comment: Also does virtualization works on my code i tried dozen of solutions but cant notice any diffrence.

Comment: Is ListView inside scrollbar?